# how to enable pop-up form to refresh data

Tags: jquery, forms

After perusing related questions on here and also looking at other sources for information, I still need help with making my simple pop-up form refresh the data that is previously entered upon clicking the cancel button. So, I have a header with a few buttons for students to click. One of those buttons is called "Search" and when it is clicked, the pop-up forms shows up so that a student may type what he/she is looking for then hit enter. Inside the form I also built a button to close the pop-up. I have the behavior I want built out; the only problem I am having is refreshing the information entered on the pop-up: so when I type something on the pop-up, then click the button to close, then click the button to open the pop-up again, the thing I typed previously still there in the pop-up input field. This seems so simple yet so hard, I have been looking, reading for hours. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!! Here is some code:
        HTML:
        
          https://www.trident.edu/"    novalidate autocomplete= "off">
          X

```
    JS:
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#search").click(function(){
      $("#fancy-search-form").show();
      $("#hover").click(function(){
      $("#fancy-search-form").hide();
      });
    });
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: it seems some of my html code was cut off so here it is!:                   <div id="input-field">
<form id= "fancy-search-form" action= "https://www.trident.edu/" novalidate autocomplete= "off">
  <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Type keywords and press enter" autocomplete="off" style="height:56px;font-size: 25px;padding-left: 4px;"><div id="hover"><a href="#">X</a></div>
</form>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Try [reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)

```
jQuery('#closebutton').on('click', function() {

    jQuery('#theForm').reset();

});
```

The above snippet is so that if you put a on click listener to the close button, you can then select & fire the reset() code.

If that does not work, try to empty each input individually:

```
jQuery('#closebutton').on('click', function() {

    jQuery('input[name="valone"]').val('');
    jQuery('input[name="valtwo"]').val('');
    // Text area
    jQuery('textarea[name="valfour"]').html('');
    // Drop down
    jQuery('select[name="selectOne"] option:selected').prop('selected', false);
    //Radio button
    jQuery('input[name="radioone"]:checked').prop('checked', false);

});
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfwzr6f3/) shows why you should do each individually instead of just blanket each form type. You don't want to clear any hidden fields you maybe using for processing ([CSFR](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/csrf/info) Token?) or any fields that are not actually in the form being closed.

Comment: pretty new to JQuery, so sorry if this sounds dumb, but should I also still include the hide() method in this? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, of course I have to add it otherwise it will not close! lol thanks I will try this now!

Comment: I believe that happens when the form isn't strictly formatted. I'll update my solution with an example on how to clear the values one by one.

Comment: Thank you!! yea, what I was trying to build is basically just a search bar - so I used a form with one text input field. Not sure if this affects things nor how :/ ...

Comment: Is the form working? Regardless, if you target the text input via the name my example should work for you.

Comment: hi, sorry I got caught up with other projects at work and kinda dropped out on this. Thank you for your examples, I may be doing something wrong because I still cant get the form to refresh once I close it :/ ....

Comment: if by working, you mean is the form connected to a database and submitting the info, then no, I currently don't have any connectivity in that sense. For now I was working on building out the behavior - getting the form to open and close - once achieving that, I moved onto trying to make its contents refresh upon closing the form. This is meant to be a search bar for students to type for things they are looking for on the site, that is all. Eventually, this will have to connect to a database but I would like to first know how to get the info inside the text input to refresh. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! I did a little bit of more probing and got it to work now! Thank you for answering my questions and thus igniting my curiosity! :)